# pg_dump with -w flag does not read from .pgpass file

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to backup my PostgreSQL database called crewdb on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from a script with the following command in it:

`pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w -C -F p -b -v -f ~/Dropbox\/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql crewdb`

I know the script that the above command runs in, itself works. When I run the above command with -W instead of -w I am prompted for a password and the backup goes ahead nicely. I am trying to automate this command within the script and want the backup to go ahead without prompting for a password thus with the -w flag. To this end I created the following file

`/home/chh1/.pgpass`

When `ls -la ~/.pgpass`

`-rw------- 1 chh1 chh1 74 Oct 15 10:00 .pgpass`

Inside the file .pgpass I placed the following text:

`# Server:Port:Database:Username:Password`

`*:*:crewdb:postgres:9Gh#$mq`

However when I run the command I get the following error output and the backup fails:

`pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w -C -F p -b -v -f ~/Dropbox\/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql crewdb`

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "crewdb" failed: FATAL:
password authentication failed for user "postgres" password retrieved from
file "/home/chh1/.pgpass" FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
"postgres" password retrieved from file "/home/chh1/.pgpass"
```

I basically followed the following process:

1) Create .pgpass file with content

```
  *:*:crewdb:postgres:9Gh#$mq
```

2) set the permissions using command

```
 sudo chmod 600 .pgpass
```

3) Set the file owner as the same user using which you logged in :

```
sudo chown chh1:chh1 .pgpass
```

4) Set PGPASSFILE environment variable :

```
 export PGPASSFILE='/home/chh1/.pgpass'
```

Now when checking with

`psql -h localhost -U postgres crewdb`

I get a similar error:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
password retrieved from file "/home/chh1/.pgpass"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
password retrieved from file "/home/chh1/.pgpass"
```

The following are the settings in my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I do much appreciate if anyone here can put me on the right path!

Comment: Can you check that .pgpass is free of any spurious character with `hexdump -C /home/chh1/.pgpass` ?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your reply. When I run `hexdump -C /home/chh1/.pgpass` I get:` 00000000  23 20 68 6f 73 74 6e 61  6d 65 3a 70 6f 72 74 3a  |# hostname:port:|
00000010  64 61 74 61 62 61 73 65  3a 75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d  |database:usernam|
00000020  65 3a 70 61 73 73 77 6f  72 64 0a 2a 3a 2a 3a 63  |e:password.*:*:c|
00000030  72 65 77 64 62 3a 70 6f  73 74 67 72 65 73 3a 39  |rewdb:postgres:9|
00000040  47 68 23 24 6d 71 20 0a                           |Gh#$mq .|
00000048`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hexadecimal dump of `.pgpass` shows that there is space character (`20`) immediately after the password and before the end of line:

```
47 68 23 24 6d 71 20 0a |Gh#$mq .
```

This space must be removed otherwise it's taken as part of the password.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the password now works. I learnt something new with the hexdump command. I had to also use flag -d crewdb and get rid of crewdb at the back of pg_dump command as it was trying to dump default database postgres and not crewdb.